# How to overcome the reservation of the number generated by sequence if it is not saved?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

It has Sequence to generate drug codes that the user enters
In the event of entering a medicine and undoing this process, the number will already be reserved for this medicine that was not entered, and thus the next medicine will be with a number that comes after the one that was reserved.

CREATE SEQUENCE F_SQ
START WITH 1
MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
MINVALUE 1
NOCYCLE
CACHE 20;
I have a sequence created using the above script. Our nightly jobs use these sequences, so on the first entry it used 1,2,3,4,5 and the next entry it started with 6 if a user doesn't save this entry   then he wanted to enter an item it started with 7 .. and so on

How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you are asking how to avoid sequence gaps ? If so... why is this a problem ?

Comment: If you really need gapless sequences then [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5JltFoe5Ho) explains what they are and demonstrates a good alternative/solution

Comment: how to avoid sequence gaps ?

Comment: you cannot avoid gaps like that.. since you assign the number way before it's actually used to persist the corresponding entity. You should block the whole database in the meanwhile to enforce such a policy.. or you should reuse numbers that were not used. But the sequence itself just goes forward. You may minimize the impact just by fetching the seq number only on INSERT instead of reserving it before the user actually fills the form

Comment: Good database design does not require consecutive keys. Keys are should have no relationship with other keys (greater or lesser, before or after), but simply be unique. Gaps are fine. If they aren't, there is a problem with the design.

Answer (score 1):

If you want gap-free sequence numbers, this video walks though an implementation of how to do it

https://youtu.be/B5JltFoe5Ho

using the code below.  But as others have said, and even as the video description says: "The first rule of gap free sequences is .... just forget about it and allow gaps :-)"

Anyway, here's the code to do it

```
create table seqs
  ( name   varchar2(100),
    constraint seqs_pk primary key ( name )
  )
organization index ;

insert into seqs
select 'SEQ'||rownum
from dual
connect by level <= 5;

select * from seqs;

create table seqs_numbers
  ( name   varchar2(100),
    num    number(10),
    state  varchar2(10),
    constraint seqs_numbers_pk primary key ( name,num ),
    constraint seqs_numbers_fk foreign key ( name) references seqs ( name ) on delete cascade,
    constraint seqs_numbers_ck check ( state in ('free','used'))
  )
organization index ;

insert into seqs_numbers
select s.name, num, 'free'
from   seqs s,
       ( select level num from dual 
         connect by level <= 1000 );
commit;

select * from seqs_numbers
where  name = 'SEQ1'
and    rownum <= 12;

create or replace
function get_seq(p_name varchar2) return number is
  l_seq number;
  cursor next_seq is
    select num
    from   seqs_numbers
    where  name = p_name
    and    state='free'
    order by num
    for update skip locked;
begin
  open next_seq;
  fetch next_seq into l_seq;
  close next_seq;
  update seqs_numbers
  set    state = 'used'
  where  name = p_name
  and    num = l_seq;
  
  return l_seq;
end;
/

set serverout on 
exec dbms_output.put_line(get_seq('SEQ1'));

select *
from   seqs_numbers
where  name = 'SEQ1'
and    num  <= 5;

exec dbms_output.put_line(get_seq('SEQ1'));

select *
from   seqs_numbers
where  name = 'SEQ1'
and    num  <= 5;

exec dbms_output.put_line(get_seq('SEQ1'));

select *
from   seqs_numbers
where  name = 'SEQ1'
and    num  <= 5;

declare
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(get_seq('SEQ1'));
  commit;
end;
/
rollback;

select *
from   seqs_numbers
where  name = 'SEQ1'
and    num  <= 5;

exec dbms_output.put_line(get_seq('SEQ1'));
commit;

select *
from   seqs_numbers
where  name = 'SEQ1'
and    num  <= 5;
```